# "Unable to Load XML.dll" when Building CRAN XML v3.98-1.10

Tags: r, xml

Trying to compile version 3.98-1.10 of R's XML package. I grabbed the 64bit 7zip files from here: https://www.zlatkovic.com/pub/libxml/64bit/

I unzipped the file, and then placed the contents of the unzipped folder's \bin, \include, and \lib into `C:\rtools40\mingw64\`(bin | include | lib) accordingly. I then ran `install_version("XML", version = "3.98-1.10", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")` in Rstudio.

It successfully makes it past the make phase to "byte-compile and lazy loading". A LOCK folder is made with all files intact, yet it errors out looking for the XML.dll in the lock:

`error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/myuser/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/00LOCK-XML/00new/XML/libs/x64/XML.dll'`

I opened the LOCK folder during a second attempt to see if the dll was truly missing, but it actually shows up - it seems to spontaneously disappear when it's needed (edit - the contents of the entire folder disappear):

[image: It does exist at some point]

My current version of XML isn't missing its dll either. Anyone encounter this issue and solve it?

Pastebin of terminal output (minus make stage) here: https://pastebin.com/ZayU5XNX

EDIT:

Found out RStudio can conveniently [install tar.gz files](https://riptutorial.com/r/example/5556/install-package-from-local-source), so I downloaded the archived version from CRAN. Running `install.packages(file.choose(), repos=NULL)` opens a navigation panel and you can select the tar.gz file wherever it was saved to. The make dialogue seems to be more verbose, but it still made it to the lazy-load step. Still the exact same error as my previous attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just using xml2 instead since it appears XML is orphaned.